# Pass function parameter from c# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript

I have ASP.NET Web Application Project.In which i want to Pass Value to a function in `javascript` from c# code-behind page.

My C# Code Snippet:-

```
//Here td_Output is TableCell

td_Output.Text = "<input type='button' style='font-size:11px;' onclick='LoadLoayaltyProgram(1,'"+Convert.ToString(Request.Form["Program"])+"');' class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' role='button' value='Add' />";
```

JavaScript Code :-

```
function LoadLoayaltyProgram(PID,ID) {
    alert(PID +" "+ ID);
}
```

When i do Inspect Element on .aspx Page in browser i see code Like :

```
<input type="button" style="font-size:11px;" onclick="LoadLoayaltyProgram(1," pid112002');'="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="button" value="Add">
```

**I am not getting any alert on click of "Add" button**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `LoadLoayaltyProgram` you are printing consequtive `'` . So, escape the `"` with `\"` so you can reuse it with something like this:

```
string program = Server.UrlEncode(Request.Form["Program"] ?? string.Empty);
td_Output.Text = String.Format("<input type='button' style='font-size:11px;' onclick='LoadLoayaltyProgram(1, \"{0}\");' class='ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all' role='button' value='Add' />", program);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  onclick="LoadLoayaltyProgram(1," pid112002');'=""
```

this look very strange  shouldnt it be something like?

```
  onclick="LoadLoayaltyProgram(1, 'pid112002')"
```